# How can I scan for all IPs of devices connected to the network using Apple's Network Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, network-framework

I want to scan for any device found in the network my device is currently connected to. I want to find their IP address and possibly more information so I can present the user a list of all devices in the network providing as much details as possible.

I have found example using `getifaddrs`. They kind of work, but, I am unable to see all of the devices I can see with an app like `IP Scanner` on the Mac app store.

In the process I have learned that the new Framework Apple is pushing is the [Network](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/) framework.

I haven't been able to find many examples on how to possibly build an IP scanner using the `Network` framework. I think I may be able to achieve that using `NWBrowser`, but I am not sure as that seems to be strictly a Bonjour play.

Does anyone have example I could follow to learn how to build an IP scanner using the new Apple Network Framework?

Comment: Use a library like [MMLanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan). The basic idea is to iterate over IPs in your subnet, send a ping packet, and if ping succeeds fetch more details like MAC address, hostname, etc.

Comment: There is no foolproof way of doing that. Hosts can be configured to not respond to scans, and Private VLANs prevent hosts in the VLAN from being able to even see each other.